# where is the rss read/unread status stored in

Tags: rss

When we fetch rss with a rss reader, does the reader mark the read/unread status or send this kind of information back to the server?

After I read a message, then I turn to another rss reader, do I will receive all the rss records marked unread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the information is stored locally on your computer, or in the case of Google Reader, on Google's server. A website sends the same RSS XML out to everyone.

Comment: so the reader do all the work as a filter, the website will send all the items it has.

Comment: It doesn't send all the items, it only sends the most recent. Many sites limit this to 10-15 items. http://stackoverflow.com/feeds as an example limits this to 30 items. Everytime your reader refreshes, it will check the ID to see which ones it has already downloaded, and then show you the new items as unread while not making duplicates.